# KiCAD: addting a micro via to a footprint

Tags: kicad, eda

I need to make a footprint in KiCAD that has a micro via. Is this possible? The footprint will sit on a 4-layer board and I need a micro via from F.Cu to In1.Cu.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but kicad footprints don't handle embedded vias.

You'll have to do with THT pad if possible, for full vias. If the requirement isn't actually a full via (like a blind or buried) you simply can't do that.

Reason: kicad footprints lives outside the board, in the libraries; they don't know the inner layers. In fact the only options available are only top, only bottom, or all the layers.

Comment: Re. last para: You're referring to all footprints, not just vias?

Comment: Yes, kicad doesn't handle special padstacks either. For example sometimes you can make different inner layers with slightly different annulus to make space for traces but in kicad you don't have the option.